# Is there any way to "seal" a token so child processes can't inherit it?

Tags: windows, winapi, uac, elevated-privileges

I am trying to find a way to allow a single process to be launched as an elevated user but prohibit this process from launching any children with it's token--in a way, sort of "sealing" the token.  The reasoning behind this is to prevent a user from launching cmd.exe and gaining full access to the system.

I've looked through the process privilege constants and I'm not seeing anything that could be used to implement this functionality.

Comment: Good idea though unfortuantely the elevated application could be anything and is unknown.  My thought pattern is gravitating toward something like:
-Create a service which launches the process as the elevated user.
-Get a reference to it's token and store this reference.
-Register a WMI listener to check for application launches--if a launched application has the same token / privileges as the elevation application, automatically kill the child process.

Comment: I imagine you could do this with a kernel-mode driver via ObRegisterCallbacks.  But it would be a very shallow protection: anyone who can make the elevated process launch cmd.exe could almost certainly make the elevated process do anything cmd.exe can do, and more.  (Including disabling your protection mechanism and *then* launching cmd.exe!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can seal the token but you can control child process creation with job objects:

```
static BOOL SpawnProcessAndTerminateGrandchildren(PTSTR Cmdline)
{
    HANDLE hJob = CreateJobObject(0, 0);
    if (!hJob) return false;

    JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION jobli;
    jobli.LimitFlags = JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_ACTIVE_PROCESS;
    jobli.ActiveProcessLimit = 1;
    BOOL retval = SetInformationJobObject(hJob, JobObjectBasicLimitInformation, &jobli, sizeof(jobli));

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    if (retval)
    {
        STARTUPINFO si;
        ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si)), si.cb = sizeof(si);
        retval = CreateProcess(0, Cmdline, 0, 0, false, CREATE_SUSPENDED|CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB|CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, 0, 0, &si, &pi);
    }
    if (retval)
    {
        if (AssignProcessToJobObject(hJob, pi.hProcess)) // This can fail if we are already in a job
        {
            ResumeThread(pi.hThread);
            WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
        }
        else
            TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    }
    CloseHandle(hJob);
    return retval;
}


int main(int argc, ...)
{
    TCHAR cmd[] = TEXT("cmd.exe /k regedit"); // cmd.exe is our child, regedit is the grandchild spawned by cmd.exe
    SpawnProcessAndTerminateGrandchildren(cmd);
    return 0;
}
```

If you want more control you can use JobObjectAssociateCompletionPortInformation so you get the JOB_OBJECT_MSG_NEW_PROCESS message each time a new child process is created.